# Unable to Sign Out of my Apple ID on my mac

Tags: macos, icloud

Whenever I clicked the sign out button, this error is prompted in my screen. The same problem persist when signing out iCloud. I'd tried resetting my password in browser, but that doesn't helps. BTW I'm using catelina V 10.15.3 (19D76)

[image: System preferences error]

Comment: Please edit the original post and add the version of macOS that is on this Mac

Comment: Same problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Some people have solved this by going to System Preferences/Internet Accounts, selecting an iCloud account there, and signing in. You need to repeat this for each iCloud account. Might be a corrupt .plist.

Do a backup, preferably 2 backups on 2 separate drives.
Quit System Preferences.

Go to Finder and select your user/home folder. With that Finder window as the front window, either select Finder/View/Show View options or go command - J.  When the View options opens, check ’Show Library Folder’. That should make your user library folder visible in your user/home folder.  Select Library. Then go to Preferences/com.apple.systempreferences.plist.  Move the .plist to your desktop.

Restart the computer, open the application, and test. If it works okay, delete the plist from the desktop.

If the application is the same, return the .plist to where you got it from, overwriting the newer one.

Comment: I have already signed in with the same email ID in Internet Account as well, when I tried to remove it, I've got an error prompt "There was an error in Internet Accounts preferences".

I've tried moving my .plist to desktop, but the same problem persist.

:(

Comment: did you restart the computer?

Comment: Yes! But nothing helps, Is there is any other way ?

Comment: well, i have no idea. maybe this link will be helpful: https://www.ikream.com/how-to-fix-macos-catalina-error-message-preferences-error-36956